# Compare two rows in AND condition

Tags: sql, compare, rows

just having a problem using the AND operator in SQL as it returns a zero result set.

I have the following table structure:

idcompany, cloudid, cloudkey, idsearchfield, type, userValue

Now I execute the following statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM filter_view 
WHERE 
    (idsearchfield = 4 and compareResearch(userValue,200) = true) 
    AND (idsearchfield = 6 and compareResearch(userValue,1) = true)
```

compareResearch ist just a function that casts the userValue and compares it to the other value and returns true if the value is equal or greater. UserValue is actually stored as a string (that's a decision made 6 years ago)

Okay, I get a zero resultset which is because both criterias in braces () are AND combined and one row can only have one idsearchfield and therefor one of the criterias won't match.

How do I get around this? I NEED the AND Comparison, but it won't work out this way.

I hope my problem is obvious :-)

Comment: Sorry, I just saw I forgot the code blocks. a_horse_with_no_name took obviously care of it. Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't replacing `AND` with `OR` work?

Comment: _idsearchfield_ cannot be at the same time **4** and **6**, so you can't use **AND**. You should use **OR** instead...

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. How can you possibly expect to find rows where `idsearchfield` is both 4 **and** 6?

Comment: If you want to compare different rows you probably need to join your table with itself. As we do not know the exact semantics - espacially the keys - we need more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you've recognised that both conditions can't ever both be true, in what way can the AND comparison be the correct one?

```
select * 
 from filter_view 
 where (idsearchfield = 4 and compareResearch(userValue,200) = true) 
   OR (idsearchfield = 6 and compareResearch(userValue,1) = true)
```

This will return 2 rows (or more). Or are you looking for some way to correlate these two rows so that they appear as a single row?

---

Okay, so making a tonne of assumptions, because you haven't included enough information in your question.

`filter_view` returns a number of columns, one of which is some form of record identifier (lets call that `ID`). It also includes the aforementioned `idsearchfield` and `userValue` columns.

What you actually want to find is those `id` values, for which one row of `filter_view` has `idsearchfield = 4 and compareResearch(userValue,200) = true` and another row of `filter_view` has `idsearchfield = 6 and compareResearch(userValue,1) = true`

The general term for this is "relational division". In this simple case, and assuming that id/idsearchfield are unique in this view, we can answer it with:

```
select id,COUNT(*) 
 from filter_view 
 where (idsearchfield = 4 and compareResearch(userValue,200) = true) 
   OR (idsearchfield = 6 and compareResearch(userValue,1) = true)
 group by id
 having COUNT(*) = 2
```

If this doesn't answer your question, you're going to have to add more info to your question, including sample data, and expected results.

Comment: But the customer's request is that only results with a value greater or equal to 200 on searchfield 4 will be listed AND only values greater or equal to 1 (or tow or 100) on searchfield 6 are shown. This works like a filter. If I use OR, it will show BOTH results, even if one of the conditions don't match :(

Comment: @Jan - I've updated my answer - am I closer to guessing your requirements?

Comment: @Jan: so you should (IMHO) use `SELECT... WHERE (idsearchfield = 4 and ...) UNION ALL SELECT... WHERE (idsearchfield = 6 and ...)`

Comment: @Marco - that would return exactly the same results as using `OR`.

Comment: @Damien, +1 for you because I think your edited question is the right one

Comment: @Jan - glad it helped. But for reference, do you see how much extra information I had to guess at, compared to what was in your question? My general recommendation for SQL questions is to include: `CREATE TABLE` statements (but remove irrelevant columns), sample data (preferably as `INSERT` statements), expected results, and as many "edge" cases as you've already managed to identify.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I will do better in the future, promised!